# angularjs function called multiple times while pushing data into array

Tags: angularjs

I am concatenating few columns into a single column and showing it on a grid. I want to push that value into an array. While doing that i am getting this error.

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:

Also i noticed that this function is called many times. I did few thing as suggested in other posts, but nothing worked. 
In the following code i am concatenating columns in the getLoss() function and i am trying to insert that value into an array.

How can i push the value into an array when the function is called for each row?

```
columnDefs: [{ field        : 'loss',
                cellTemplate : '<div id="grid-cell-template">
                                   {{grid.appScope.getLoss(row.entity)}}</div>'}]

var totalLoss = []; 

$scope.getLoss = function(rowEntity) {

            var ls1 = rowEntity.loss1;
            var ls2 = rowEntity.loss2;
            var ls3 = rowEntity.loss3;

           loss= ls1+ls2+ls3;
           console.log("loss=", loss);

           totalLoss.push(loss);

            return loss;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling the function like an expression, call it inside the `ng-init`

```
columnDefs: [{ field        : 'loss',
                cellTemplate : '<div id="grid-cell-template" ng-init="grid.appScope.getLoss(row.entity)">
                                   {{loss}}</div>'}]
```

change the `loss` variable to a scope and make your `totalLoss` empty inside the function.

```
var totalLoss = [];
$scope.getLoss = function(rowEntity) {

           totalLoss = [];
           var ls1 = rowEntity.loss1;
           var ls2 = rowEntity.loss2;
           var ls3 = rowEntity.loss3;

           $scope.loss= ls1+ls2+ls3;
           console.log("loss=", loss);

           totalLoss.push(loss);

};
```

Comment: even then the function is called many times and only the last value is inside the array and not the previous values. also i want to use that array in another function so how to declare it inside this function instead of globally..

Comment: hey the good news is function has stopped multiple times. But i am not able to show loss value in grid/cellTemplate. also the array holds only lost value. so i removed totalLoss[ ] from function. But is it right.

Comment: can u create a plnkr

Comment: I am not good with that. can you please take Teamviewer ? the issue is here {{loss}}. what should the function return here?

Comment: can't use team viewer. function should not return anything. it should work after assigning the value to `loss`

Comment: Oh ok. Only issue i am not able to show value on grid. Other than that no issues i think as of now.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. Please explain, i will post that part.

Comment: how do you convert the string in to HTML tag

Comment: you mean celltemplate ? i use ui-grid.

Comment: If you want i will post this whole html page.

Comment: Please check the whole code [here](https://paste.ofcode.org/ZB797UabfmJa82YM599uUv) instead of loss its plan there.

Comment: If i use {{grid.appScope.loss}} instead of {{loss}} it prints the last value in all columns. How to make it print each rows own value.

Comment: @ sachila  any help please